# how to store response public api array in database

Tags: node.js, express

I have created API,to get the *pincode* related area details. When I enter *pincode* it shows area details of that *pincode* , if that detail exist in my databse. But sometimes that *pincode* related details are not available in my database, so i need to call it by public API and also store that passed *pincode* and area details in my database. In Command prompt i am getting response,of *PostOffice* array. So the details which I am getting needs to be stored in Database. How can I do that?

I am able to store *pincode* which I am passing in API , and in other fields such as Name,Description etc. runturns as `empty[]` in database.

I am using `mlab` for it

```
Changed code: i am able to store pincode & i need to store array result,on cammand prompt displaying the body,includes the PostOffice array,in which having Name,Description,Branchtype...etc I need to store all this field.schema contains this fields.
                    router.get('/pincode/:pincode',function(req, res) {
           Pincode.find({pincode :                 req.params.pincode},function(error,pincode ){ 
                 //when pincode not found in db         
            if(pincode.length == ''){
                console.log("gfhg");
                    function searchAndSave(pincode, callback){
             var request = require('request');
           res.statusCode = 302;         
           request('http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/'+pincode,function (error, res, body) {
                   if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                        var pincodeData = new Pincode({
                     pincode:pincode,
               body:body.PostOffice
                 });
                 pincodeData.save(function (err,results) {
                  if (err) {
                   return callback(err);
                 }
              else {
                 console.log(body);
                return callback(null,pincodeData);
                  }
                       });
                    }else      
              //no record found
                return callback(null,null);
                      }
                   }); 

                     }
                             searchAndSave(req.params.pincode,function(errInSearchAndSave,result){
                      if(errInSearchAndSave){
                     console.log("error : ", errInSearchAndSave);
                       }else{
                      //pincode result return from api and db 
                          res.json(result);

                    }
                     })
                 }else{
                    //pincode found in db         
                   res.json(pincode);
             }
               });  
                 });
```

Comment: can u explain briefly what do u want .

Comment: What database do you use? This question seems overly broad.

Comment: i have create a api,to get the pincode related area details.When i enter pincode it shows area details of that pincode if that detail is exist in my databse.but sometime that pincode related details are not exist in my database ,so i need to call it by public api and also store that passed pincode and area details in my database.on cammand prompt i get response,in which having PostOffice array.that area details i want to store in my database,so how to do it?

Comment: i am able to store pincode which i passing in api,and in other fields such as Name,Description etc. return as empty[] in database.

Comment: i am using mlab for it

Comment: The user has explained her question in comments. And earlier it was not clear what she wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to check if result found in db or not and create separate callback function for better clarification

```
//create a seprate function for search and store db
function searchAndSave(pincode, callback){

  var request = require('request');
  res.statusCode = 302;         

  request('http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/'+pincode,function (error, res, body) {
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
      var pincodeData = new Pincode({
        pincode:pincode,
        body:body.PostOffice.Name
      });
      pincodeData.save(function (err,results) {
        if (err) {
         return callback(err);
       }
       else {
        console.log(body);

        return callback(null,pincodeData);
      }
    });

    }else{
        //no recoord found
        return callback(null,null);
      }

    }

 router.get('/pincode/:pincode',function(req, res) {

     Pincode.find({pincode : req.params.pincode},function(error,pincode ){ 

         //when pincode not found in db         
         if(!pincode){

           searchAndSave(req.params.pincode,function(errInSearchAndSave,result){
            if(errInSearchAndSave){
              console.log("error : ", errInSearchAndSave);
            }else{
              //pincode result return from api and db 
              res.json(result);

            }

          })

         }else{
        //pincode found in db         
        res.json(pincode);
      }

    });  


   });
```

Comment: by adding above code,when i am testing in postman it shows error as Cannot GET /api/pincodes/pincode/413533

Comment: make sure you defined proper route in your code , try moving function searchAndSave into route function get('/pincode/:pincode',function(req, res) {

Comment: i have firstly take a route code & in that taking route function.i am able to save pincode.on cammand prompt display the body of called public pincode api.from that in need only PostOffice array's, field need to store in database